# Reorder items in a list using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I have an observable array of items. One of the properties of an 'item' is 'position', which denotes the item's position in the list. I would like to be able to reorder items on the page by having a drop-down with positions next to each item. When a user selects a position for an item in the drop down, the position values for any items affected get recalculated.

The problem that I'm running into is when I attempt to utilize the event binding for the drop down - I can't figure out a way to pass the original & new positions to my 'reposition' function.

I'm sure this could be accomplished by using array indexes for this simple example, but I'm trying to see if I can avoid that.

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4tqahpkg/3/

```
<div class='liveExample'>
<ul data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
    <li>
        <div>   <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has Position:
            <select id="pos" data-bind=" options: orderedItems,
                    optionsText: function(item) { return item.position   },
                    optionsValue: function(item){ return item.position   },
                    value: position,
                    event: { change: function () {reposition($data.name(), position()); } } "></select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
var Item = function (name, position) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.position = ko.observable(position);

}

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.items = [
    new Item("item Three", "3"),
    new Item("item One", "1"),
    new Item("item Two", "2"),
    new Item("item Five", "5"),
    new Item("item Four", "4"),
    new Item("item Six", "6")];


    self.orderedItems = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items, function (item) {
            return true;
        }).sort(function (a, b) {
            var value1 = "",
                value2 = "";
            value1 = a.position() ? a.position() : "";
            value2 = b.position() ? b.position() : "";
            return value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 < value2 ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });

    self.curName = ko.observable();

    self.curItem = ko.computed(function (name) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items, function (item) {
            return item.name() == self.curName();
        });
    });

    self.reposition = function (name, newPosition) {

        self.curName(name);
        origPosition = self.curItem()[0].position();

        if (origPosition < newPosition) {
            for (var x = 0; x < orderedItems.length; x++) {
                if (origPosition < newPosition && self.orderedItems()[x].position() >= origPosition && self.orderedItems()[x].position() < newPosition) {
                    self.orderedItems()[x].position(self.orderedItems()[x].position() - 1);
                }

                if (origPosition > newPosition && self.orderedItems()[x].position() >= newPosition && self.orderedItems()[x].position() < origPosition) {
                    self.orderedItems()[x].position(self.orderedItems()[x].position() + 1);
                }

                if (self.orderedItems().name() == name) {
                    self.orderedItems()[x].position(newPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    };


};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: So strange interface... Why not use list reorder by drag and drop?

Comment: The list might contain hundreds of items and might be unwieldy for drag and drop. This would be a shortcut to that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access the old position, but you haven't defined any storage for it. Each item will have to have an oldPosition variable (I've made a private one) and have a subscription on `position` that calls your `reposition` function before updating oldPosition.

I've done a little re-architecting of your design, which I thought was a bit convoluted. I haven't implemented `reposition`, which I guess you want to shift other items' positions so you don't have duplicates.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  var Item = function(name, pos) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.position = ko.observable(pos);
    var oldPosition = pos;
    this.position.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      self.reposition(this, oldPosition, newValue);
      oldPosition = newValue;
    }, this);
  };

  this.items = [
    new Item("item Three", "3"),
    new Item("item One", "1"),
    new Item("item Two", "2"),
    new Item("item Five", "5"),
    new Item("item Four", "4"),
    new Item("item Six", "6")
  ];


  self.orderedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items, function(item) {
      return true;
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.position() - b.position();
    });
  });

  self.curName = ko.observable();

  self.reposition = function(item, oldPosition, newPosition) {
    console.debug("Reposition", item, oldPosition, newPosition);
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
    <li>
      <div> <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has Position:
        <select id="pos" data-bind=" options: orderedItems,
      optionsText: 'position',
      optionsValue: 'position',
      value: position "></select>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. My solution was awkward because I thought that when the select change event occurred, I would be able to read the old position value before it was updated with the new one.

Comment: @PaulP Note also that you're not calling `new` on your viewmodel constructor. I didn't catch that. It will make things misbehave.

Comment: Thanks Roy - much appreciated!

Comment: Roy - in my reposition function, I loop through the items to reassign their positions. However, this doesn't quite work because this recursively triggers additional 'reposition' runs until I exceed the max stack size :) . Can you think of another way to reassign positions in this function? Thanks!

Comment: It's messy. I have been looking at it, and don't have a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I'm relatively inexperienced in JS & KnockoutJS and just wanted to confirm there was no 'right way' of doing it. Seems like the solution is to not bind the selects to the array of items and to simply loop through the collection of selects manually and update them.